# Make multiple firestore queries in a cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to create a scheduled cloud function that is generating employees bonus at the end of each month.
To do that, i need a list of all employees, of all invoices of that user and of all existing bonus, all contained in firestore collections.
So i need 3 firestore collections but can't find any solution on how to do query that in a cloud function.

i tried this for now :

```
exports.generateBonus = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  var listEmployee = [];
  var listInvoice = [];
  const employeeRef = admin.firestore().collection('employee');
  const invoiceRef = admin.firestore().collection('invoice');
  const promiseFacture = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      return factureRef.get();
  })
  .then(list_invoice => {
    listInvoice = list_invoice.docs.map(doc => {
      return doc.data();
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("got an error",error);        
  });
  const promiseEmployee = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    return employeeRef.get();
  })
  .then(list_employee => {
    listEmployee = list_user.docs.map(doc => {
      return doc.data();
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("got an error",error);        
  });
  Promise.all([promiseInvoice, promiseEmployee])
  .then((values) => {
    console.log(values);
    return res.send('ok');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
});
```

But it return me two empty arrays in 1 sec

Does anyone know how to do this ? Thank you

Comment: You can use `Promise.all()`. Note that your question is too vague for SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you ! But i already tried with Promise.all and it doesn't work... may be i'm not using it properly.
Sorry about that, i edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following, using [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), should do the trick:

```
exports.generateBonus = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    const employeesRef = admin.firestore().collection('employee');
    const invoicesRef = admin.firestore().collection('invoice');

    const [employeesSnapshot, invoicesSnapshot] = await Promise.all([employeesRef.get(), invoicesRef.get()]);

    const listEmployees = employeesSnapshot.docs;
    const listInvoices = invoicesSnapshot.docs;

    //Logging
    listEmployees.forEach(snap => {
       console.log(snap.data());
    });
    listInvoices.forEach(snap => {
       console.log(snap.data());
    });

    //...
    res.status(200).send(...);   //Adapt the ... to a meaningful value
});
```

---

Note that the [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#get) method returns a Promise, so you don't need to wrap it in another Promise.

---

(note that I have added an s to all the collections/snapshots variables names).

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your help ! Unfortunately i'm still facing the same issue... The cloud function finished in 1s and th arrays are empty.

Comment: I've just tested it and I confirm it works. I've added some `console.log()` statements to the code, you should check your Cloud Function console and verify what is logged there.

Comment: Sorry, yes it's working thank you so much ! I was testing on emulator (that is showing an empty list) but once deployed, i can see the list in the logs.